# Using loops to automate functions-Python 3

Tags: function, python-3.x, loops

Is there a way to use a for loop to automate a function? e.g
if i write..

```
def foo (a number):
    return (a number)

for i in range(10):
    print(foo('1{}').format(str(i))
```

Comes out with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'`

Comment: `for i in range(10): print(foo(10 + i))`, or use `for i in range(10, 20): print(foo(i))`. Integers are not strings, just use arithmetics to produce arguments.

Comment: So, no, `str.format()` only works on strings, because it is a string method. You don't have a string here.  Also, the code you posted would throw a *`SyntaxError` exception*, not the error you claim to get.

Comment: So that code is just an example what i am actually using is trying to concatenate a string, my bad should have made that as an example. Though it would be the same for numericals aswell, will change it.

Comment: Why do you think you need code generation in the first place? You can generate a string containing an expression, then use `eval()` on that, but in 99.9% of cases, there are *much better ways* of doing what you want. What is the *actual problem* you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am changing this because it didn't really answer your question, but its a lot simpler than you are trying to make it. Really all it is, is a function that is called and updated by a loop. So, let's try that:

```
def foo(num):
    print(num)
num = 0
for i in range(1,10,1):
    foo(num + i)
```

So, what I've done here is taken your script and changed it. To start with, "a number" as a parameter will cause syntax errors while trying to define them. So I changed it to "num".

Then, I've used a simple print statement to print out the number that is coming in. This could be removed if you just wanted a loop with it cycling it through numbers. And of course changing "foo(num + i)" to "print(num + i)".

The "num = 0" sets a variable so we can use it later.

Regards,
Jerry